# How does a Dart mixin access its parent class?

Tags: dart

I have a case where I need a mixin to be able to return its parent class, and I don't know how to do that. Here is my code:

```
class Foo<T extends String> extends SuperClass<T> with MyMixin<T, Foo> {
  Foo(value) : super(value);
}

class Bar<T extends int> extends SuperClass<T> with MyMixin<T, Bar> {
  Bar(value) : super(value);
}

abstract class SuperClass<T> {
  final T value;
  SuperClass(this.value);
}

mixin MyMixin<T, U> on SuperClass<T> {
  U? doSomethingOrNull() {
    return value is String ? null : this;
  }
}
```

So, `Foo` and `Bar` are both extending `SuperClass`, which contains the value with a generic type. `Foo` and `Bar` can have a different value type, but they are sharing some logic, which is why I am doing like this.

`Foo` and `Bar` are sharing a method called `doSomethingOrNull()`. But I want to be able to create `Baz` which will not have `doSomethingOrNull()`. That's why I created a mixin to hold  `doSomethingOrNull()`.

I want `doSomethingOrNull()` to return null if a text fails, or to return `Foo,Bar,...` if it succeeds. But I realize that `this` in a mixin has the type of the mixin, and not of the parent class. So how do I make `doSomethingOrNull()` return its parent class? Is it possible to do it in a mixin?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not do `return value is String ? null : (this as U);`?